# Gitlab CI: build fails while cloning repo from Gitlab: fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I set up Gitlab CI (4.3) and can't solve the following problem while building:

fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab-ci-token:my-gitlab-ci-token@gitlab.server.com/namespace/project_name.git/'

Gitlab (6.7.0) and Gitlab Shell (1.9.1) work perfectly fine. I followed the installation guide and I don't think I missed anything. Token is exactly the same, Gitlab server and the namespace / project name are also ok. Maybe there is some issue with non-standard ssh port on Gitlab server but I don't really know, there were no problems with "normal" cloning and pushing to Gitlab. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to check auth manually. Just go to gitlab host under gitlab user, and try to use ssh to connect to gitlab-ci host with token. It works? Look at auth logs. What's there?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you meant to use Gitlab CI token to ssh to gitlab_ci user at Gitlab CI from git user at Gitlab host? I probablby didn't het something here...

Comment: I checked the logs: in auth.log at Gitlab server there wasn't anything related to connecting to the server while cloning repo, also nothing in logs from gitlab-shell, in Gitlab production.log just: Started GET "/namespace/project.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack"

Maybe it's related to cloning through http itself, not Gitlab Ci.

Comment: Are you sure your gitlab.server.com is valid hostname? Probably your server can't resolve that name or something. You also need to check logs on the host with gitlab-ci. Oh wait. Maybe you just forgot to add deploy ssh key?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid host name. Even if I use real username / password combination, it works so it can't also be related to cloning.

Nothing to find on CI server in logs. I added both ssh keys from gitlab_ci and gitlab_ci_runner users to deploy keys, just to make sure I tried everything and still the same error.

Comment: I just solved it, I was using 6.7.0 version, 6.7.1 fixes Gitlab CI integration, update to the current one worked. Thank you, Alex, for your help.

Comment: Oh. Good to know. ;-) You can answer your question now by self. Well done!